# SQLAlchemy max function

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy how do you run a `max` query?

For example

```sql
SELECT max(id) FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import func 

session.query(func.max(Table.column))
```

Answer (score 92):

For anyone coming here from google 4 years later, `func` is now in [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func).

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

session.query(func.max(Table.column))
```

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import func` is valid as of the latest version (1.13). https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L50

Answer (score 24):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
max_id = session.query(func.max(Table.column)).scalar()
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want, for example:

```sql
Select max(table_column) from some_table where other_field=10
```

You can do

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(func.max(table_column)).filter_by(other_field=10)
```

Comment: @jon_darkstar You only need `==` if you use `.filter`, with `.filter_by` the arguments are for a query with `==` assumed and multiple arguments put together with `AND`.

Comment: Where is the usage of `some_table` in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLAlchemy 2.0-style syntax, the ORM code would be

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, select

with Session() as s:
    result = session.scalar(select(func.max(Table.column)))
```

and the core version:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.scalar(select(func.max(users.c.id)))
```

In both cases the use of `scalar` gives us the result as an integer directly, rather than having to extract from a wrapper object.