# Select min and max date from table with conditions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy Core, how can I select the min and max dates from a table given a set of conditions?

In plain SQL, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(date) as "min_date", MAX(date) as "max_date" 
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_column=value
```

I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

table = Table('my_table', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
s = select([table.c.date])]).where(table.c.my_column == my_value)
pd.read_sql_query(func.min(s), engine.connect())
```

Which gives me the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: `select(func.min(table.c.date)).where(table.c.my_column == my_value)`?

Comment: @bbayles I swore I tried that... thanks for the hint.  This worked:  `select([func.MIN(table.c.date).label('min_date'),
func.MAX(table.c.date).label('max_date')]).where(table.c.my_column == my_value)`. I originally had brackets `select([func.MIN([table.c.date])`

Comment: Looks like a decent answer for this already posted. [SQLAlchemy 0.5.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750118/sqlalchemy-0-5-8-max-function)