# SQLAlchemy get max value

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to get the max value in a table for an attribute, the attribute is risk:

I am running:

```
func.max(HostsModel.risk)
```

I get back:

```
<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.max at 0x10f0721d0; max>
```

How do I actually get the value from this?

I see these as the available functions:

```
 dir(func.max(HostsModel.risk))
['__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__or__', '__radd__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__visit_name__', '__weakref__', '_allow_label_resolve', '_alt_names', '_annotate', '_annotations', '_bind', '_bind_param', '_clone', '_cloned_set', '_cols_populated', '_compare_name_for_result', '_compiler', '_compiler_dispatch', '_constructor', '_copy_internals', '_deannotate', '_execute_on_connection', '_execution_options', '_from_objects', '_generate', '_hide_froms', '_init_collections', '_is_clone_of', '_is_from_container', '_is_join', '_is_lexical_equivalent', '_is_select', '_key_label', '_label', '_make_proxy', '_memoized_property', '_negate', '_order_by_label_element', '_params', '_populate_column_collection', '_refresh_for_new_column', '_render_label_in_columns_clause', '_reset_exported', '_resolve_label', '_select_iterable', '_textual', '_translate_schema', '_with_annotations', 'alias', 'all_', 'anon_label', 'any_', 'asc', 'base_columns', 'between', 'bind', 'bool_op', 'c', 'cast', 'clause_expr', 'clauses', 'coerce_arguments', 'collate', 'columns', 'comparator', 'compare', 'compile', 'concat', 'contains', 'correspond_on_equivalents', 'corresponding_column', 'count', 'desc', 'description', 'distinct', 'endswith', 'execute', 'execution_options', 'expression', 'filter', 'foreign_keys', 'get_children', 'identifier', 'ilike', 'in_', 'is_', 'is_clause_element', 'is_derived_from', 'is_distinct_from', 'is_selectable', 'isnot', 'isnot_distinct_from', 'join', 'key', 'label', 'lateral', 'like', 'match', 'name', 'named_with_column', 'notilike', 'notin_', 'notlike', 'nullsfirst', 'nullslast', 'op', 'operate', 'outerjoin', 'over', 'packagenames', 'params', 'primary_key', 'proxy_set', 'replace_selectable', 'reverse_operate', 'scalar', 'schema', 'select', 'selectable', 'self_group', 'shares_lineage', 'startswith', 'supports_execution', 'tablesample', 'timetuple', 'type', 'unique_params', 'within_group', 'within_group_type']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750118/sqlalchemy-0-5-8-max-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830980/sqlalchemy-simple-example-of-sum-average-min-max

Comment: The result of `func.max(HostsModel.risk)` is an SQL expression object that you use in a query that you execute.

Comment: See @IljaEverilä's link to a pre-existing dupe of this question. What you want is basically `session.query(func.max(HostsModel.risk))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy 0.5.8 Max function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750118/sqlalchemy-0-5-8-max-function)

Answer (score 11):

Per the comments, you can see that this relates to some other answers, though none cover the whole solution.  Rewritten, if you'd like to access the `max(HostsModel.risk)` value directly:

```
session.query(func.max(HostsModel.risk)).scalar()
```

You need to `query` using the `max` function, then get its `scalar` result.  Since this query can only have one result (assuming no other groupings are specified), you'll end up with a value equal to the maximum `HostsModel.risk` value.

This also extends to other aggregates, e.g. `avg`, `min`, etc.  Leveraging scalar in this way also works when filtering to a single column and record, even without an aggregate defined.

Comment: This advice worked for me. I first saw it about 10 minutes ago, decided it looked unappealing, then wasted time searching for other solutions.

For me I got: ```max_id = session.query(func.max(SqlPage.id)).scalar()``` which turned out to be 6 of class 'int' just like I wanted.

And of course you need to do this at the top of your file: ```from sqlalchemy import func```